# How to get data in C# with RestClient from a database, but not all data in one call, but in several calls

Tags: c#, api, http, pagination

I am getting data from a database table in sql with a RestClient call. However, I would like to retrieve the data in several calls and not just one RestClient call. At the moment my table doesn't have that many elements, but it will have more than 100,000 data rows later on, so if I retrieve all the data with a single RestCient, it will probably crash. I'm new to APIs and I have seen that this must be done with pagination, but I am struggling a lot to do this. At the moment I am retrieving the data from my sql table as follows (and it works fine). I get a list of type Access with all the elements in my SQL table. I would like to get the same list but calling the RestClient several times to avoid the call from crashing when y have many thousands of data rows:

```
public void GetAccess()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://ip+port");
        var request = new RestRequest("GetAccess", Method.Get);
        var Response = client.Execute(request);

        if (Response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Access>>(Response.Content);
            
        }
    }

    public class Access
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Surname{ get; set; }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Pagination you limit the number of records returned by each call to a subset of the total results available.
In retrieving the full set of results you need to indicate which subset you are after each time you request data.

For example you could have a generic class (in this case type T is your `Access` class:

```
public class PagedResult<T> where T: class
{
    public PagedResult(IEnumerable<T> items, int totalCount)
    {
        Items = items;
        TotalCount = totalCount;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }

    public int TotalCount { get; }
}
```

So a `PagedResult` contains a list or array of class instances and an indicator of the total number of results that are available.
Note that this is **not** the number of results in the `Items` collection.

You API call would stem from something like:

```
        Task<PagedResult<T>> GetAllPagedResult(int index, uint maxResults = 100);
```

So in use, each time you make a call you ask for say 100 results starting from 0, then 100 starting from 100, then 100 starting form 200 etc.

Eventually you will have less than 100 results returned.

If you wish to you could expand the `PagedResult` that is returned from the call to include the requested index and maybe the number of results requested. Then when handled asynchronously you would know which block of data the results refer to.

This may be especially important if you're using pagination and wish to obtain data from a previous data block e.g., populating a data list that the user can scroll back and forth on.